# Ninja Forms, jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ninja-forms

I'm just Ninja Forms on this page: https://www.summerboardingcourses.co.uk/uksummerschools/

The conditional logic i've setup doesn't seem to be working, and when I remove this line, calling jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then the forms conditional logic starts working again.

I've been told by Ninja Forms that this usually happens when jQuery has been included twice on a page, but I can't find jQuery being called anywhere again on this page. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you check the console on your page you can see a couple of errors in your page: `$ is not a function` and `init is not defined`. The first error means that you're attempting to use jQuery before it has been included in the page. The latter means that you're trying to call a function named `init`before it has been defined.

Comment: In fact checking the source of your page it appears you've commented out the reference to jQuery.js and left only jQuery.migrate.js - you need both.

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks - I'll take a look into the errors, much of the jQuery was setup by a previous developer. I've commented out the other jQuery.js because its stopping the conditional logic on the form from working, and I need to test the form. When I comment out the jQuery then the conditional logic in the form works, as soon as I put it back in the form stops working - any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's virtually impossible to debug this I'm afraid